# plot function with large interval values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, largenumber

I'm trying to plot `|sin(x)|/x` in range `x=[1e27,1e33]`.

```
x=np.logspace(27,33,1000000)
plt.plot(abs(np.sin(x))/x)
plt.xscale('log')
```

The answer has to be a smooth damping oscillator but this is what I get:
[image]

I guess this is because of the large numbers I'm working with, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

In `plt.plot(abs(np.sin(x))/x)` you only specified the y-coordinates, hence matplotlib used integers for the x-coordinates. Since you have 1000000 x-points, matplotlib x-axis goes from 0 to 1e06.

Try this:

```py
plt.plot(x, abs(np.sin(x))/x)
```

Comment: thank you, I believe importing x-coordinate just makes those errors in the first plot unvisible but doesn't solve the problem. actually what I need is a numerical values of `abs(np.sin(x))/x` in that interval as a list.